# InaccessibleWSDLException error from SOAP generated client in JAVA

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client, spring-ws

We are working with service provider's wsdl which is not discoverable due to security reason and they provide us a bunch of files including wsdl ,xsd etc.We need to access the provider's api. For these reason we have done these following things:

1. We have generated a web service client using netbean 8.0 form **desktop location (Local File )**
2. Using generated client code we have called the api using these following code

> ```
> URL url = new URL("http://serverip:port/payment/services/MgrService");    
> MgrService svc = new MgrService(url);          
> Response response = svc.getMgrServicePort().apiRequest(request);
> ```

but getting these exception

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://serviceip:port/payment/services/MgrService
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://serviceip:port/payment/services/MgrService?wsdl

    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:260)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:231)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
```

By Wireshark, we have noticed that it is calling a **get method** with no soap body, where it should call only **post method** . We have tested the api using soapUI , service is ok . We also getting successful response using raw xml soap request.

Is it possible to work with **generated client** both for **JAX-WS and Spring WS** when WSDL is not discoverable ? or it only work with **JAX-WS**'s wsdl file.
If so then do we need to edit wsdl? or some other approach

Comment: Hi there. How did you solve this? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After few research, I have found these !

1)For Spring WS, generated client is not working (As like Netbean Generated SOAP client)

2) This link help me a lot to consume a Spring-WS service using **Spring STS**
[Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/)

but few things need to be done before you proceed

a) fix maven-jaxb2-plugin version to lower version (0.12.1)

b) add a binding.xjb file with these contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

other wise xjc will not work

3) Copy wsdl & xsd files to local project directory and pom configuration will
be as follows (for scenario where wsdl is not hosted for security reason)

```
<configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
```

3)**It is not recommended to edit the wsdl file**